# PHP/MySQL retrieve image path

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently learning MySQL and php5. I am currently having problems displaying my data with a php script. I am learning to use db paths and struggling with bringing out the data.

Here is my mysql table

```
+----+------+------------------------------+
| id | name | path                         |
+----+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | test | test                         |
|  2 | 1    | /masonry-practice/flag/1.gif |
|  3 | 2    | /masonry-practice/flag/2.gif |
+----+------+------------------------------+
```

Here is my php code

```
  <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM img");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['path'];
echo "<br>";
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: How you want to display? code is fine.

Comment: What error message are you getting? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: This seems to check out, what is it that you want to do, show the images themselves? If so, you'll want to add a `<img src=...` around your `$row['path']`

Comment: @Sadikhasan yeah, just need to get the image paths out. I want to eventual move this to dynamically display images, however I need the image paths to show up so I can advance to the next part of what I want to do.

Comment: @GWW the data is not being displayed and I am pretty sure I did this correctly. I just used this from w3schools

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want to dynamically display images, however the paths are not showing up when I run the php code.

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: nvm, I got it to working somehow... This just got frustrating but I will move to the next part and try adding the image tag that Fred-ii- brought up

Answer (score 0):

You must use this to get the values

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

And a better way to do your task will be

```
<?php

  $con=new mysqli(("localhost","root","password","db");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM img");

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['path'];
echo "<br>";
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();

/* close connection */
$con->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
and execute the script on shell to get issue

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$conn = New mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASS, NAME);
if (!$conn)
{
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `img`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['path']; 
echo "<br>";
} 
?>
```